# Issue with Integrating the Stripe Billing Portal using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I am a little embarrassed asking this question here since for anyone who has done this the answer will be real simple. I have tried several times asking Stripe Support but they simply keep referring me to the documentation (which is incomplete). I am building my first integration to the Stripe Billing Portal https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal using .Net

The code snippet below is taken from their site and it references the class SessionCreateOptions. My simple question is "what is the fully qualified namespace to this class in Stripe" as Visual Studio Cannot find it.

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_47ZQVRjCoUpDACp40ICpzZKA00qYqRydc0";

[HttpPost("create-customer-portal-session")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CustomerPortal()
{
  // Authenticate your user.
  var options = **new SessionCreateOptions**
  {
    Customer = "{{ CUSTOMER_ID }}",
    ReturnUrl = "https://example.com/account",
  };
  var service = new SessionService();
  var session = service.Create(options);

  return Response.Redirect(session.Url);
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I have resolved this, I was using an old version of Stripe.net and the class is in Stripe.BillingPortal - Sorry

Comment: Yep. Just found out that the class is in Stripe.BillingPortal. Could you provide insight on the Customer property? `{{ CUSTOMER_ID }}` does the customer id have to be enclosed in double curly braces? Seems kind of odd to me.

Comment: {{ CUSTOMER_ID }} is simply a token you need to replace with your desired Stripe Customer Id.